# Find the locus of the centroid of the triangle?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, locus

> A plane moves so that its  distance from the origin is a constant $p$. Write  down the equation of the locus of the centroid of the triangle formed by its intersection with  the three coordinates plane.

I was thinking about this  question many times,  but i could not get any hint  to find the  locus of the centroid of the triangle .
But i know that how  to find the centroid of triangle  we have to add (x+y+z/3,X+Y+Z/3), i don't know the locus  of the centroid of the  triangle.

if anbody help me i would be very thankful to him

Comment: So the plane is always tangent to the sphere?

Answer (score 1):

The equation of a variable plane in intercept form is $$\frac xa+\frac yb+ \frac zc=1$$

Here, $a,b$ and $c$ are intercept on $x,y$ and $z$ axes.

Given, it's distance from origin is constant $$\frac{\Big|\Big(\frac xa+\frac yb+ \frac zc-1\Big)_{x=y=z=0}\Big|}{\sqrt{\frac {1}{a^2}+\frac {1}{b^2}+\frac {1}{c^2}}}=p(\text{constant})$$

And centroid of triangle $$(x,y,z)=\left(\frac a3,\frac b3,\frac c3\right)$$

Therefore you get $$\frac{1}{p^2}=\frac {1}{a^2}+\frac {1}{b^2}+\frac {1}{c^2}$$

Also, $a=3x,b=3y$ and $c=3z$

$$\implies \frac{1}{p^2}=\frac {1}{9x^2}+\frac {1}{9y^2}+\frac {1}{9z^2}$$

Hence the desired locus is : 
$$\color{blue}{\frac {1}{x^2}+\frac {1}{y^2}+\frac {1}{z^2}=\frac{9}{p^2}}$$

Comment: thanks a lot@ jaideep khare,, but   i don't know   where i haveto  put this centroid coordinates and make a equation

Comment: What about the plane $z=p$?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I don't understand what you want to say.

Comment: @lomberlego Check my edit.

Comment: The plane given by $z=p$ doesn't have an $x$- or a $y$-intercept.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe In that case, $a=b=\infty$. It's just that simple. BTW, we don't take so much care while finding a locus just like while doing indefinite integration, we don't take care of domain/range.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ac+by+cz+d=0$ be an equation of the plain.

Thus, $abc\neq0$ and $$\frac{|d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}=p,$$
which gives $$|d|=p\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}.$$

Let $A\left(\frac{-d}{a},0,0\right)$, $B\left(0,-\frac{d}{b},0\right)$ and $C\left(0,0,-\frac{d}{c}\right)$ and for the centroid $M$ we obtain
$$M\left(\frac{-d}{3a},\frac{-d}{3b},\frac{-d}{3c}\right),$$
which gives
$$\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}=\frac{9(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{d^2}=\frac{9}{p^2}$$

Comment: thanks  a  lots  @ michael Rozenberg

Comment: @lomber lego You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec s$ be a vector of length $p$.  Then the plane's equation is $\langle\vec s,\vec x\rangle=p^2$.  Provided that no coordinate of $\vec s$ is zero, the intercepts are obviously 
$$\frac{p^2}{s_k}\vec e_k\quad\text{for $k=1,2,3$}$$
where $\vec e_k$ denote the $k^\text{th}$ unit vector.

The result may be easily generalized to arbitrary dimensions.